# Android: Why does my view fill the entire screen and not display the buttons at bottom

Tags: android, layout

How do I stop my view from filling the entire screen and not showing my buttons at the bottom of the screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
<com.vig.comix.ImageZoomView
    android:id="@+id/zoomview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_below="@+id/zoomview"    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> 
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="0px" /> 
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="0px" /> 
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnMove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="0px" /> 
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:width="0px" /> 
</LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I change my code and put the buttons at the top, it works fine.  I have tried relative layouts, linear layouts, lauout weights, ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your xml so we can see the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting android:layout_below in your LinearLayout. Try removing that and put

```
android:layout_above="@+id/myLinearLayout"
```

inside your ImageZoomView. Of course giving your LinearLayout the same id.

Comment: I wish I could tell you why, but the only thing I know is that I've been having the same problems myself. And the only thing fixing it is building the layout from the bottom up, having elements stack on top of each other instead of top down with layouts below each other.

Comment: The items are rendered in the order on the xml file so other things are covering them up.  You can always add an item id to a resources xml file in advance instead of using +id if you run into needing to reference an id earlier but need the view later down in the layout.

Comment: Your ImageZoomView was probably covering up the LinearLayout.  You can tell the layout system to avoid this problem by forcing it to constrain the height of the ImageZoomView using layout_above.  Another useful thing you can do is specify something as fill_parent in height, but specified as below one layout and above another - that will cause it to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` can be tricky to work with. I try to stick with `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout`. Here is a sketch of the layout I would use in your case:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <ImageZoomView layout_weight="1" layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" layout_height="wrap_content">
        ... buttons ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Heights and widths are `fill_parent` when not mentioned. The `layout_weight` attribute on the `ImageZoomView` will cause it to expand as far as it can without squishing your bottom buttons.

Comment: This solution also worked.  I was so close before.  I put the layout_weight on the button's linear layout instead of on the Zoomview.  When I put it on both or just the zoomview, it works.

Comment: I find LinearLayouts to be less complicated. Might just be me though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the layout_weight is causing issues? Also it doesn't seem like you're give the items an object to be positioned relative to?

Comment: I am sorry I can't seem to format the code correctly.  Isn't the android:layout_below="@+id/zoomview" clause what the linear layout is relative to?

Comment: Ah sorry missed a bit of it. The relative positioning looks fine. You should set image button's width to 0dip since you're using the weight parameter (since you want it to stretch horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

to this:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.  Don't I want the relative layout to occupy the entire parent?  It is the zoomview that I don't want to take up the entire parent.